# Oracle Database unsigned integer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, create-table

I want too know ,If Oracle Database support unsigned int(number) how I can use it or if not what is alternative of this?
I don't need way to put condition for SQL syntax because all my data is positive and it's important unsigned int for performance and storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that Oracle provides a specific datatype for unsigned integers. It provides a single datatype to store fixed numeric values, called `NUMBER`, whose precision and scale can be adjusted as needed.

In Oracle, the so-called `INT` datatype is a syntactical sugar provided for ANSI compatibility, which internaly maps to `NUMBER`.

I would recommend a number with a `0` scale (that's an integer), and a check constraint to ensure that it is positive:

```
create table mytable (
    id number(20, 0) check (id >= 0)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no *unsigned integer* as native datatype in Oracle. There's the `NUMBER` datatype. However, you can use `INT`, e.g.

```
SQL> create table test (id int);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (id) values (-1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test (id) values (25.335);

1 row created.

SQL> select * From test;

        ID
----------
        -1
        25

SQL>
```

As you can see, it accepts both positive and negative values (decimals are truncated).

In order to make it *positive*, add a constraint:

```
SQL> truncate table test;

Table truncated.

SQL> alter table test add constraint ch_id_pos check (id >= 0);

Table altered.

SQL> insert into test (id) values (-1);
insert into test (id) values (-1)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CH_ID_POS) violated


SQL>
```